Is it possible to create sort of macro for bison grammar rule?
Consider this pseudo example of bison grammar
command : 
    TOK_A a_command { $$.obj_a = std::move($2); }
  | TOK_B b_command { $$.obj_b = std::move($2); }
  | TOK_C c_command { $$.obj_c = std::move($2); }
  ....

and each command_X is something like this
command_a: TOK_A1 a_params1 | TOK_A2 a_params2| ...
command_b: TOK_B1 b_params1 | TOK_B2 b_params2 | ...
command_b: TOK_C1 c_params1 | TOK_C2 c_params2 | ...

It should kinda prse lines like this (it all works fine in real code, there is no issue here)
TOK_A TOK_A1 (123)
TOK_A TOK_A2 ("str")

But now let's say I'd like to be able to parse multiple TOK_XN arguments in one line like this
TOK_A TOK_A1 (123) TOK_A1 (234) TOK_A1 (356) ...
TOK_A TOK_A2 ("str") TOK_A2 ("str1") TOK_A2 ("st2") ...

It is quite easy to achieve, just instead of X_command non-terminal I could present X_command_list like this
a_command_list : a_command | a_command_list a_command;

Ignore the potential type issues here, assume everything can be assigned correctly.
Now my question is how can I prevent creating this silly X_command_list for every single command? Is there any kind of macro like this
#define list_command(cmdName) cmdName##_command_list : cmdName##_command | cmdName##_command_list cmdName##_command;

and then use it like this
command : 
    TOK_A list_command(a) { $$.obj_a = std::move($2); }
  | TOK_B list_command(b) { $$.obj_b = std::move($2); }
  | TOK_C list_command(c) { $$.obj_c = std::move($2); }
  ....

Any kind of "templates"/"macro" available for that?

There's nothing like that built-in in Bison (IIRC), but you could always run the Bison source file through the standard C++ preprocessor.

@Someprogrammerdude I can't say I really understand what you mean. What should I run through the preprocessor? Could you please give any example?

The preprocessor is a separate program cpp or cpp.exe that can interpret your #define instruction and expand it in the rest of the file. You could then do something like cpp foo.yy.in > foo.yy in your build system.

The problem with macros is that macro expansion can occur anywhere. Further, you may have macros defined in the grammar, and you don't want these expanded. I recommend that you use another template engine. We have the same problem in Antlr grammars.

Maybe consider having a single token TOK instead of TOK_A, TOK_B, TOK_C, ... and store the A/B/C in some separate variable.
